# Sql print all rows in a single line with a while loop

Tags: sql, database

I want to print the names in my Employees table side by side in a single line.

The code i tried :

```
DECLARE @AllNames Varchar(1000)                                   
Select @AllNames = COALESCE(@AllNames + ',','')+ ISNULL(Name, 'N/A') from Employees SELECT @AllNames
```

I want to do this with a while not a function. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You could try [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)., but unfortunately you do not want to use a function, Why do you not want to use a function ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query with While Loop.

```
DECLARE
@counter    INT = 1,
@max        INT = 0,
@Output     nvarchar(max) = ''

-- Declare a variable of type TABLE. It will be used as a temporary table.
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
    [Id]        int identity,
    [Name]   nvarchar(max)
 )

-- Insert your required data in the variable of type TABLE
INSERT INTO @myTable
SELECT Name
FROM Employees

-- Initialize the @max variable. We'll use thie variable in the next WHILE loop.
SELECT @max = COUNT(ID) FROM @myTable

-- Loop 
 WHILE @counter <= @max
 BEGIN

-- Do whatever you want with each row in your table variable filtering by the Id column
SET @Output = @Output + (SELECT Name FROM @myTable WHERE Id = @counter) + ', '

SET @counter = @counter + 1
END

SELECT @Output
```